# Use Robotium as intro/demo presentation for Android Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, robotium

I have an Android project in Android Studio. As part of this app, I'd like to include a demo, which automatically clicks things, like buttons, type text in `EditTexts`, swipe left and right, just to show the possibilities within the app. I made a script with `Robotium`, and it works just fine, but, I can only start it from within Android Studio. However, I would now like to include that script in the app. I added the dependencies to `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And the demo script, just like any ordinary Android JUnit test:

```
public class Demo extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    private Solo solo;

    public TestApk() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        //run demo script
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {}
}
```

But it keeps throwing `NoClassDefFoundError` whenever I call `new Demo()`.

How can I include an Android JUnit test script as part of a regular app/APK?

Or is there a commonly used method to run a demo that I am unaware of?

Comment: Would be nice if downvoter explained the downvote...

Answer (score 2):

`Robotium` is a test framework build exactly for testing, not to provide user fine app intro.

If you want make an introduction to your app's user check how to create beatiful and functional intro. You can use for this purpose great libraries like

- Paolo Rotolo's AppIntro: https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro
- Heinrich Reimer's https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro
- Introduction: https://github.com/rubengees/introduction

You can also creat your new brand one using:

- Aimation: https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/AppIntroAnimation
- InkViewPager: https://github.com/DavidPacioianu/InkPageIndicator

Check apps like `Todoist`, `Udacity`, `Gmail` and more to check how they provide user an introduction.

If you want to show a user specific action or view, try to use: https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView

Check how `Evernote` already provides user this purpose.

Hope it will help